# DIFFERENT TASKS ASSIGNED TO DIFFERENT INSTANCES OF FORK() OF A PROCESS IN C

Tags: linux, process, fork, real-time, context-switch

Can I assign different task to different instances of `fork()` of a process in C ?
like for example:

`program.c` has been forked 3 times

```
int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    pid = fork();
    pid = fork();
}
```

now to every instance of `fork()` I want to do different thing, Can I do this? with forks ? or any other method if favorable? :)

PS: I am testing Real Time Linux and want to check the performance of the Context Switching through forks through Time Constraint.

Comment: fork() and exec() work great together !!

Comment: Read the manual page for `fork`, it explains how to tell whether you are in the parent process or the child after it returns, and you can use an `if (pid == ...)` to "do something different", whether that's calling different functions, or `exec`-ing a different program or whatever...

Comment: I think I have an idea of knowing whether a process is parent and when it is a child, the problem is solved, I did not have to use forks that way, 1 fork and many exec can help it out. What I wanted to check was the performance of RTOS with handling of the fork processes.
To my short answer that I have discovered, No, different tasks cannot be assigned to fork processes, you need to program it in a different way. :) .

Comment: Don't use all capitals, e.g. in the title. It is considered as shouting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use posix process..

posix_spawn( &Pid,ProgramPath.c_str(), & FileActions,& SpawnAttr,argv,envp);

Check its documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/posix_spawn.2.html).

Answer (score 0):

You *always* have to test the result of [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) (in particular, to handle error cases), and do different things for 0 result (successful in child process), positive result (successful in parent process), negative result (failure, so use `perror`). So according to that result you can do different things. Often you end up invoking [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) for the child process (when `fork` gives 0), and you usually setup things (e.g. for [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) thru [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)-s) *before* calling `fork`.

<sup>So to assign a different task after a `fork` just execute different code according to result of `fork`</sup>

You should **read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)**. It has *several chapters* explaining all that (so I won't take the time to explain it here).

You could be interested in [pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) (implemented using [clone(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) and [futex(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/futex.7.html), which you should not use directly unless you are implementing your thread library, which is not reasonable).

Try also to [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) several programs (including some shell and some basic commands). It will tell which [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) they are calling. See also [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html).