# Proper Way to Fork Process

Tags: c, fork

I'm trying to send a request to a server, and fork it each time beforehand:

```
int main(void)
{
    // request send
    fork();
// errx() error handling
    return 0;
}
```

This however only causes 1 fork, then the program crashes. I've been browsing through some docs online and cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong and why it isn't forking each time it attempts to query a server.

Comment: Dare I ask what *this* is supposed to be doing: `i = i++` ??

Comment: What is `errx()`?

Comment: It would probably be much easier to do this with a *single* watchdog. What you have now sends both parent and child into `errx`, which I assume terminates your program.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26023726/841108) answer to a nearly duplicate question

Comment: Please don't edit the question so as to invalidate existing answers/comments.  It is confusing for future users/visitors.

Comment: @MartinJames the edit was to only to simplify the question, and doesn't seem to invalidate the answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main problem is execution path. Both parent and child process continue to `errx`, which apparently kills the active process, meaning no iterations in the parent or child. You don't check the result of `fork`, which is purposely there to help you tell if the function (a) worked, and (b) the current process is the parent or just-forked child.

You're better off setting up the parent process to be a watchdog, and launching the child processes to be guarded. A simple shell example is below, which sequentially launches child processes, waiting for each to terminate.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            // handle child process here
            sleep(1);
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }

        if (pid < 0)
        {
            perror("Failed to launch child process");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("child %d started\n", (int)pid);
            int res = 0;
            pid = wait(&res);
            printf("child %d exited, result = %d\n", (int)pid, WEXITSTATUS(res));
        }

    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Example Output**

```
child 72916 started
child 72916 exited, result = 0
child 72917 started
child 72917 exited, result = 0
child 72919 started
child 72919 exited, result = 0
child 72920 started
child 72920 exited, result = 0
child 72921 started
child 72921 exited, result = 0
child 72923 started
child 72923 exited, result = 0
child 72924 started
child 72924 exited, result = 0
child 72925 started
child 72925 exited, result = 0
child 72926 started
child 72926 exited, result = 0
child 72927 started
child 72927 exited, result = 0
```

---

**Monitoring Batches**

For a more complicated version, the following launches child processes in batches of three, then waits for all three to terminate before launching the next batch. This is repeated three times for a total of nine processes total (ten, including the parent watchdog).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    for (int i=0; i<3; ++i)
    {
        // batch launch loop
        int n_children = 3;
        for (int j=0; j<3; ++j)
        {
            pid_t pid = fork();
            if (pid == 0)
            {
                // handle child process here
                sleep(1);
                return EXIT_SUCCESS;
            }
            else if (pid < 0)
            {
                perror("Failed to launch child process");
                --n_children;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("child %d started\n", (int)pid);
            }
        }

        // batch wait loop
        for (int j=0; j<n_children; ++j)
        {
            int res;
            pid_t pid = wait(&res);
            printf("child %d exited, result = %d\n", (int)pid, WEXITSTATUS(res));
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Example Output**

```
child 73190 started
child 73191 started
child 73192 started
child 73190 exited, result = 0
child 73191 exited, result = 0
child 73192 exited, result = 0
child 73193 started
child 73194 started
child 73195 started
child 73194 exited, result = 0
child 73193 exited, result = 0
child 73195 exited, result = 0
child 73196 started
child 73197 started
child 73198 started
child 73196 exited, result = 0
child 73197 exited, result = 0
child 73198 exited, result = 0
```

Hopefully you'll find some of that helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You have to keep in mind that both the main (first) process and the child (second one) will execute the same code, namely the `errx` function call. This thing is done usually with and if/else checking for the return value of fork. That would be something like this:

```
if (fork() == 0) {
    // you are in the child thread here
}
else {
    // and here you are in the parent
}
```

and you split your logic between the 2 threads. If not, the threads will both go on executing the same code until the quit the execution.

Comment: You usually don't want your main thread to exit and have other threads running, even if it's possible. Have your main thread wait after the others and have different child threads spawning each others and exiting when needed.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for your insight I'll work on it!

Comment: No problem, hope you will succeed. If the answer seems good and helpful to you, you can also mark it as accepted :-)

Comment: You forgot to handle the failure of  `fork`, when it returns a negative value

Comment: keep in mind if there is no exec, code after if{}else{} block will be executed by both parent and child